# Fixed element flicker within an iframe on iOS

Tags: ios, css, iframe, fixed, flicker

I know there seems to be a lot out there about this, but none of the solutions seem to fix my issue.

I am trying to apply a fixed button to the bottom of my screen **within an iframe**. With my current implementation, I am experiencing a terrible flicker with the button on iOS Safari whenever I scroll.

Here's essentially what I have:

**HTML**

```
<iframe>
 <body>
  <div class="app">
   <div class="app-content">
     <div class="card">
       <h1>Header</h1>
       <p>Content</p>
     </div>
     <button class="fixed-button">This is flickering</button>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</iframe>
```

**CSS**

```
iframe {
 border: none;
 position: absolute;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 top: 0; left: 0;
}

app {
 -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
 overflow:auto;
 position:absolute;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
}

fixed-button {
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 1rem;
}
```

I've got a WIP on my site here http://jaredrauh.com/iframe-fixed-elements-ios/. Any suggestions would be amazing.

Comment: I don't think a "fix" exists. Here's a good hack I found...

https://hackernoon.com/amp-ios-scrolling-and-position-fixed-redo-the-wrapper-approach-8874f0ee7876#.cfxvii4p5